# How to access a dynamic array in two different functions c++

Tags: c++, pointers

I need to access a dynamic array in two different functions. The changes made to it in one need to transfer over to the other.

These are the functions:

```
void populate(int size, int *ptr)
{
    ptr = new int[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        ptr[i] = rand() % 51;
    }
}

void display(int size, int *ptr)
{
    for (int i=0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << ptr[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

it is called in the main as

```
int* ptr = NULL;
```

Answer (score 5):

In `populate`, you are attempting to make a pointer you pass to the function point to a dynamically allocated array. But you pass the pointer by *value*. This has no effect on the caller side, and results in a memory leak. You need to pass either the pointer by reference:

```
void populate(int size, int*& ptr)
                            ^
```

or return it

```
int* populate(int size)
{
   int* ptr = new int[size];
   ....
   return ptr;
}
```

But the easiest and safest thing to do would be to use an `std::vector<int>` for both functions instead. For example

```
std::vector<int> populate(size_t size)
{
    std::vector<int> v(size);
    for (auto& i : v)
    {
        i = rand() % 51;
    }
    return v;
}

void display(const std::vector<int>& v)
{
  for (auto i : v)
  {
    std::cout << ptr[i] << std::endl;
  }
}
```

This way, it is clear what is being returned, and the caller doesn't have to read up on whether they have to manage the resources pointed at by a raw pointer.

Note that `populate` can be replaced by a call to [`std::generate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate), and `display` by a call to [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy).

Answer (score 1):

You have to remember that when passing arguments to a function, they are passed *by value*, meaning they are copied. So when you pass a pointer to a function, the pointer is copied, and when you modify that pointer (like e.g. `ptr = new int[size]`) you only modify the local copy.

In C++ you can pass arguments *by reference* which means that you can modify the arguments and their changes will be reflected in the calling function:

```
void populate(int size, int*& ptr)
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to make the first function return the pointer and store it in another variable. You can then send it to the second function.

Comment: Good contribution, but would be even better with a coded example :)

Answer (score 0):

usually when you need to pass a pointer to a function which does the initialization of the pointer, you either pass p**ointer to pointer** or the function **returns a pointer**.

The easiest way to do it is to simply return a pointer from the populate function:

```
int* populate(int size, int *ptr)
{
    ptr = new int[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        ptr[i] = rand() % 51;
    }
    return ptr;
}

 int*p = populate(N,p);   


display(int size, int *ptr)
{
    for (int i=0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << ptr[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

The reason why simply passing the pointer does not work is that the pointer is passed by value, which means a **local copy of the pointer is created locally in your function**; that local copy is being initialized and destroyed when you exit the function